# I must add login to navbar in React

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I must add login system to navbar, but when I login in anywhere, navbar does not appear. How can I solve it?

Navbar shows normally with no login system.

Navbar is on App.js.

> authLinks - Section just for authenticated users (Dashboard and Log out buttons)
>
> guestLinks - Section just for not-authenticated users (Login form in here)

My navbar + login:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { logout } from "../../actions/auth";
import { login } from "../../actions/auth";

const Navbar = ({ auth: { isAuthenticated, loading }, login, logout }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = e =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login(email, password);
  };

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
  }

  const authLinks = (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/dashboard">
          <i className="fas fa-user" /> <span className="hide-sm">Dashboard</span>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a onClick={logout} href="#!">
          <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt" />{" "}
          <span className="hide-sm">Log out</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );

  const guestLinks = (
    <form
      className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-login"
      onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}
    >
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          className="form-control mr-sm-2"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email Address"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          className="form-control mr-sm-2 my-sm-0"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
    </form>
  );

  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <h1>
        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
          <i className="fas fa-crown"></i>
          <br />
          nawdic
        </Link>
      </h1>
      {!loading && (
        <Fragment>{isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}</Fragment>
      )}
    </nav>
  );
};

Navbar.propTypes = {
  logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login, logout })(Navbar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user is logged in Navbar returns redirect component which is not the navbar itself

```
if (isAuthenticated) {
  return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
}
```

Since isAuthenticated is passed to Navbar it shouldn't be responsible for redirecting in this case.
Try to move the Redirect thing to router as a best practice